# Question about Strong Law of Large Numbers in Breiman

Tags: probability, limits, law-of-large-numbers

I was reading through Breiman's Probability on Strong Large Numbers and got stuck on a part of its proof. It goes:

Let $\Omega$={0,1}$^\mathbb N$ and $S_n$=$\sum_{k=1}^n\omega_k$.

If $C$={$\omega\in\Omega$ : $\lim_{n\to \infty}$$S_n$($\omega$)/$n$=${1\over 2}$}, and $\hat C$={$\omega\in\Omega$ : $\lim_{m\to \infty}$$S_{m^2}$($\omega$)/$n$=${1\over 2}$}, 
then $C=\hat C$.

I tried to prove this on my own, but cannot seem to make any progress, or find where to start. Any help on how to start this proof or the proof itself would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: Grammar, formatting

Comment: Why $m^2$?  What is the relationship (if any) between $m$ and $n$?

Comment: He shows that $P(\hat C)=1$ and then extends that to $P(C)=1$ in the text. There is a proof in the text for this issue, but I cannot seem to fathom the logic behind it.

Comment: Typo? I think the condition in $\hat C$ should be $\lim_{m\to\infty} S_{m^2}(\omega)/m^2=\frac12$

Comment: You're right. That's a typo on my part. Edited now, thanks!

Comment: Correcting the typo gets $\hat{C}=C$.  $P(C)=1$ is not apparent.

Comment: How is $\hat C$=$C$ apparent? That's the part I'm failing to understand/come up with a proof for. $P(C)=1$ is proven in the following proof in the text, which I understand. Just cannot wrap my head around why or how $\hat C$=$C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Breiman's proof in front of me, so I can attempt to explain it more clearly.

The assertion that $C=\hat C$ is an assertion about sequences of zeros and ones, so we can suppress the $\omega$ by focusing on just one sequence.

The inclusion $C\subset \hat C$ is trivial: if a sequence $x_n$ converges to zero as $n\to\infty$, then it also converges along the sequence $n_k:=k^2$. So the hard direction is proving that if $S_{m^2}/m^2\to\frac12$, then so does $S_n/n$.

Suppose $S_{m^2}/m^2\to\frac12$. Let $\epsilon>0$. To show $S_n/n\to\frac12$, the obvious first step is to write, using the triangle inequality,
$$
\left|\frac{S_n}n-\frac12\right|\le\left|\frac{S_n}n-\frac{S_{m^2}}{m^2}\right|+
\left|\frac{S_{m^2}}{m^2}-\frac12\right|.\tag1
$$
But the second term on the RHS of (1) tends to $0$ as $m\to\infty$. So for all large $m$, say $m\ge M$, we have
$$
\left|\frac{S_{m^2}}{m^2}-\frac12\right|<\epsilon.\tag2
$$
 Now pick $n\ge M^2$. For this $n$, find an $m\ge M$ such that $m^2\le n<(m+1)^2$. Confirm that this implies that $|n-m^2|\le 2m$. By the triangle inequality, we can bound the first term on the RHS of (1):
$$
\left|\frac{S_n}n-\frac{S_{m^2}}{m^2}\right|\le
\left|\frac{S_n}n-\frac{S_n}{m^2}\right|+
\left|\frac{S_n}{m^2}-\frac{S_{m^2}}{m^2}\right|.\tag3
$$
Since $|S_n|\le n$, bound the first term on the RHS of (3) by $n\left|\frac 1n-\frac1{m^2}\right|\le\frac2m$. Bound the second term by $\frac1{m^2}|n-m^2|$, since the distance between $S_n$ and $S_{m^2}$ is at most the number of steps from time $m^2$ to time $n$. Adding these, it follows that the RHS of (3) is at most $\frac4m\le\frac4M$. Putting (2) and (3) together, we have
$$
\left|\frac{S_n}n-\frac12\right|\le\frac4M+\epsilon
$$
whenever $n\ge M^2$. This implies that (1) is less than $2\epsilon$ for all large $n$, and we're done.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "suppressing the $\omega$ by focusing on just one sequence"? Sorry if it is something elementary, I'm a fairly new student of analysis :/.

Comment: @pilotmath To eliminate clutter I'm dropping all the occurrences of $\omega$ in the proof, so instead of writing $S_n(\omega)$ I write $S_n$. So now $S_n$ now looks like a sequence of real numbers.

Comment: $S_n$ as a sequence of real numbers as in all the possible sums of 0's and 1's right? Also, is there a reason why we pick a specific $n\geq M^2$, and an $m$ accordingly?

Comment: @pilotmath $S_n$ is the partial sum of a specific sequence of 0's and 1's. Each $\omega$ gives rise to one sequence. We are picking $n\ge M^2$ to set up the standard epsilon-N proof for convergence of a sequence: For each $\epsilon$ you have to find an $N$ such that $|x_n-a|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>N$. Here $N$ is chosen to be $M^2$.

Comment: thank you so much! It all makes sense now!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why $N$ is chosen to be $M^2$?

Comment: @user282639 We choose $n\ge M^2$ so that "find $m\ge M$ such that $m^2\le n<(m+1)^2$" is possible. If $n$ is not $\ge M^2$ then the $m$ we find might be too small to exceed $M$.

Comment: @user282639 ... and the condition $m\ge M$ is needed later on.

Comment: do we need to specify the value of this $M$, say $M = \varepsilon / 4$?

Comment: @user282639 $M$ is supposed to be a big integer, not something small like $\epsilon/8$. It is enough to assert that $M$ exists; no need to specify its value. The $M$ exists because, by the convergence of $S_{m^2}/m^2$ to $\frac12$, we know that $|S_{m^2}/m^2-\frac12|$ is less than $\epsilon$ for all large enough $m$.

Comment: what do you mean by "number of steps from time $m^2$ to time $n$"?

Comment: @user282639 number of terms of the sequence between index $m^2$ and index $n$. For example there are 4 steps from $S_9$ to $S_{13}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $m^{2} \leq n \leq (m+1)^{2}$ then $\frac {S_m^{2}} {m^{2}} \frac {m^{2}} n \leq \frac {S_n} n \leq \frac {S_{m+1}^{2}} {(m+1)^{2}} \frac {(m+1)^{2}} n $. Just verify that $\frac {m^{2}} n$ and $\frac {(m+1)^{2}} n $ tend to $1$ as $ n\to \infty$. [$\frac {m^{2}} {(m+1)^{2}} \leq\frac {m^{2}} n\leq 1$ and $\frac {m^{2}} {(m+1)^{2}} \to 1$ because $m \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. Similar argument for $\frac {(m+1)^{2}} n $.